# openweather unix datetimestamp to local datetime in php

Tags: php, api, datetime-format, openweathermap

I am trying to convert the sunrise and the sunset unix epoch datetimestamp provided by the Openweather API call to my local datetime. And i am getting really discrepancy results.
The sunrise value is 1594726338 and the sunset value is 1594775338. However, when i convert that to my local date time, the sunrise is 2020-07-14 17:02:18 and the sunset value is 2020-07-15 06:38:58, absolutely way off target. I have tried looking that up on online date/time converter sites and they return the same results.
First i tried this:

*

```
<?php
    $uep=1594726338;
    $t = date('r',$uep);
?>
```

- 

Then i tried this:

```
<?php

    $uep=1594726338;
    $t = date('r',$uep);
    $savedtime = $t;
    $servertime = ini_get('date.timezone');
    $time = strtotime($savedtime . $servertime);
    $dateInLocal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
    echo $dateInLocal;
?>
```

I have the correct datetime set in the php.ini file. I have also read something about dividing the unix epoch by 1000. Or maybe i am not converting it properly or misreading the results?

Regards,

Ochen

Comment: Your first attempt works correctly with my weather data ('sunrise' => 1594695557, "2020-07-14 04:59", TimeZone:Europe/Berlin ). I think your problem is with calling the weather API. The correct location must be specified there.

Comment: I am using co-ordinates instead of location. Is that a potential problem? The OpenWeather API documentation says it would work with co-ords as well...

Comment: No, I use that too. You can also check the coordinates coord->lat and coord->lon in the response.

Comment: yuup, am getting the right lat and long. See the returned JSON: {"lat":25.91,"lon":-93.73,"timezone":"Etc/GMT+6","timezone_offset":-21600,"current":{"dt":1594737745,"sunrise":1594726338,"sunset":1594775338,"temp":28.47,"feels_like":31.43,"pressure":1015,"humidity":77,"dew_point":24.04,"uvi":11.9,"clouds":28,"wind_speed":4.11,"wind_deg":196,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}]},"daily":[{"dt":1594749600,"sunrise":1594726338,"sunset":1594775338,"temp":{"day":28.96,"min":28.47,"max":29.2,"night":28.68,"eve":29.16,"morn":28.47},"feels_like":.....

Comment: Incorrect! "lon": - 93.73 is somewhere in the Gulf of Mexico. Notice the minus sign.

Comment: yeah, i figured that out late last night.... apologies. Thanks forspottinng that, it's seems to be fixed  now.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is always in UTC, so you need to convert it to local zone, e.g.:

```php
$ts = 1560281377;
$dt = new DateTime('@' . $ts);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: i have already converted it  to my timezone. Anyway, i tried the above code you provided but it is still outputting sunrise as 2020-07-14 17:02:18.

Comment: @OchenAo what is your timezone?

Comment: Asia/Kolkata. That's  also been configured on my php.ini